# vbs, how to add some code to the current code?

Tags: file, vbscript, addition

I want to execute a code in the script with knowing the path of the path of that code i want to execute (its a .vbs file). I don't know should I use Eval or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your second .vbs file is a complete script that your first .vbs should execute 'as if from a command line', then use .Run (or .Exec) as Marco advised.

If your second .vbs is a module containing functions/subs/classes some of them you want to use in your first .vbs, do an Execute[Global] on a .ReadAll() of the second file.

If you can/want to recode your first file as a .wsf, you can use a script tag with a src attribute to 'import' your module. Minimalistic demo:

The module:

```
'' mod.vbs
Function SampleFunc()
  SampleFunc = "mod::SampleFunc()"
End Function
```

Main file:

```
<job>
 <script language="VBScript" src="mod.vbs" />
 <script language="VBScript">
  WScript.Echo WScript.ScriptName
  WScript.Echo SampleFunc()
 </script>
</job>
```

Output:

```
cscript main.wsf
main.wsf
mod::SampleFunc()
```

Another strategy is to put your module code in a .wsc file; that gives you a COM component you can register and use via CreateObject() or simply load via GetObject( `"script:<filespec>"`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WSHShell.Run "wscript " & strFileName, , True
```